# Does remainder of 2^-1 divide by 7 exists? (mod 7) Decimal?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am confused as to how decimal plays a part compared to the multiplicative inverse.

For example, I know that $2^2\equiv 2^5\equiv 4\bmod 7$ (the pattern is 1,2,4, for every power of 3)

This then implies that $2^{-1}\equiv 4 \bmod 7 .$

However $2^{-1}$ is a decimal, and the definition of the divides I know is specific for integers. When searched online, it says the remainders for decimals do not exist.

So does $2^{-1}$ divide by 7  exists? Is it different from $2^{-1}$ mod 7?

Comment: in modular arithmetic, $2^{-1}$ is not a decimal

Comment: Note that here $2^{-1}$ means the inverse of $2$, i.e $2^{-1} =a $ if $a\cdot 2 \equiv 1 \mod 7$. It denotes the inverse of $2$ in the group $(\mathbb{Z_7},\times_7)$, where $\times_7$ means multiplication modulo $7$.

Comment: Symbols like “$ a^{-1} $” and “$\sqrt{a}$” are dependent on the group $a$ lives in. The first (your question) is just notation for “the thing that when multiplied by $a$ gives me 1”. Of course, in normal arithmetic that would “look like” a decimal expansion of $1/a$, but we aren’t working in the rational numbers! Rather, we’re working in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, so one must understand what multiplication means here. And here, $2 \cdot 4 = 1$, so $2^{-1}=4$. On that note, it is a good exercise to compute $\sqrt{2}$ mod 7.

Answer (score 1):

$2^{-1}\equiv 4 \bmod 7$ makes perfect sense because $2 \cdot 4 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n